# updateSliderInput doesn't update the value until tab is updated

Tags: shiny

When using `updateSliderInput()` on a `sliderInput` that is in a tab that isn't currently visible, the slider doesn't actually get updated until it is visible. This is not the case with other inputs I tested and causing problems if another input/output depends on that slider.

Example: this app has two tabs, each with a `sliderInput`. There is an output specifying what the value of the slider in tab2 is. Whenever the slider in tab1 is changed, the slider in tab2 is updated to match it. Note that the output should change whenever tab1 slider is moved, but it only gets updated after seeing tab2 slider.

```
library(shiny)
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = 
    navbarPage(
      "title",
      tabPanel(
        "tab1",
        sliderInput("num1", "Set slider in tab2 to:", 1, 10, 1),
        textOutput("foo")
      ),
      tabPanel(
        "tab2",
        sliderInput("num2", "num", 1, 10, 1)
      )
    )
  ,
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$foo <- renderText(sprintf("Number in tab2 is: %s", input$num2))
    observe({
      updateSliderInput(session, "num2", value = input$num1)
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: Not sure what it is, but the code above is working for me, I am on `shiny version 1.7.1`

Comment: Your code is working for me too. My version is `1.7.1`.

Comment: I have similar problems in more complicated setup, where the slider has a date value. Yet, your example is working for me. My Shiny version is 1.7.2.